# Python3 Numpy multiply : Could not broadcast together with shapes (10, 10000) (10000, 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, valueerror, elementwise-operations

I'm having an issue using numpy in python3 at this instruction:

```
res = ( np.multiply(error, v_sigmop ))
```

I'm trying to multiply element-wise but I'm having this weird error :

```
res = ( np.multiply(error, v_sigmop ))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,10000) (10000,10)
```

This operation isn't illegal since the amount of columns matches the amount of rows of the second array...

Any idea?

Comment: Use np.matmul. multiply is element-wise multiplication, where the arrays have to be the same or broadcastable sizes.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : matmut do not do the same than multiply.
I tried to multiply 2 3 by 3 matrix of ones and I obtained this: `[[3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]] (3, 3) #matmul
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]] (3, 3) #multiply
`

Comment: Right, it doesn't. Your last sentence implies that you want matrix multiplication, not element-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are maybe trying to multiple 2 matrixes with shape `(r1,c)` and `(c,r2)`

You can use `A.dot(B)` for your problem, that will multiple 2 matrixes.

This is example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
>>> b = np.arange(8).reshape((4,2))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> b
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
>>> a.dot(b)
array([[ 28,  34],
       [ 76,  98],
       [124, 162]])
```

Hope it will help you!

**Edit**

Because you don't want multiple 2 matrixes, you want to multiple as scalar, but multiple scalar is not your operation, that mean you can't multiple 2 matrixes such as:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

multiple with

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

That is not valid operation for multiple 2 scalar.

You only have operations:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])


# Multiple all elements with a scalar
>>> np.multiply(a,0)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])


# Multiple each column with a column
>>> b = np.arange(3).reshape((3,1))
>>> b
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
>>> np.multiply(a,b)
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])


# Multiple each row with a row
>>> b = np.arange(4).reshape((1,4))
>>> b
array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
>>> np.multiply(a,b)
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9],
       [ 0,  5, 12, 21],
       [ 0,  9, 20, 33]])


# Multiple each element with the same shape
>>> b = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> np.multiply(a,b)
array([[  0,   1,   4,   9],
       [ 16,  25,  36,  49],
       [ 64,  81, 100, 121]])
```

Comment: dot is for scalar product right?

`import numpy as np

foo = np.ones( (3,3)  )
bar = np.ones( (3,3)  )

a = np.dot(foo, bar)
b = np.multiply(foo, bar)

print(a, a.shape)
print(b, b.shape)
`
For this code I'm getting the following output:

`[[3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]
 [3. 3. 3.]] (3, 3)
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]] (3, 3)
`
Which isn't the operation I expected...

Comment: @Irchad, I've edited my answer, hope it will help you :)